Range Accrual pricing calculation
There is a discussion in https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/rangeaccrual.asp which basically states how the CF from a Range Accrual would be determined.
I wonder if there is any standard pricing method available to price such instrument. Any pointer will be very helpful.
Thanks
